# A method being called from another class doesn't return the value it is supposed to in iOS (MVC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, method-call

I have implemented MVC in my project. In Model I have a class DBHandler containing below method which is suppose to return me names of saved items

```
- (NSMutableArray *) displayAllItems
{
NSString* selectAllResume = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from Items"];
sqlite3_stmt* selectStatement = (sqlite3_stmt *)[self getStatement:selectAllResume];
while(sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
@try {
    ResumeDC *resume = [[ResumeDC alloc] init];
    NSString *result_output = @"";
int numberOfCoulmns = 1;
    for (int  a=0; a<numberOfCoulmns; a++)
    {


      resume.resumeName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, a)];
        NSString *formatout = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", resume.resumeName];
        result_output = [result_output stringByAppendingString: formatout];
    }

    [dataList addObject:result_output]; // the value in the datalist is empty later on.

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"We were unable to find the files.");
}
return dataList;
   }
}
```

In View, I have a class SavedItems. Here in viewDidLoad() I am trying to access all the data being read by the above method and get it displayed in the tableview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
self.tvMine.delegate = self;
self.tvMine.dataSource = self;



GET_DBHANDLER
[dbHandler displayAllItems];

mydataList = dbHandler.dataList;
numberOfRows = [mydataList count];
[tvMine reloadData];
}
```

And thats how I am getting it displayed in the table (Just providing it, else the below code is perfect).

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    }
    if ([mydataList count] > 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [mydataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

But I get nothing in return from the displayAllItems when it is being called outside it's class.

Comment: What value is it returning? Nil?

Comment: Don't you think so to write this `return dataList;` statement outside `while loop`. Also check whether you have initialized `dataList` or not.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, the fatalist is an NSArray so it contain the value but when it is being called outside the class then it doesn't have anything in it. I am just having issues with getting access to it from another class.

Comment: @jrturton, inside the class it gives the value it is suppose to return lets say ItemsXYZ, but when I call it from outside the class then dataList is empty. Just check whether my method call is alright or not? Thanks.

Comment: @ejazdogar `dataList` should be `NSMutableArray` not `NSArray`. and also it should be initialized.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, Mybad it is NSMutableArray not NSArray.

Answer (score -1):

The answer should have been what was being asked. I asked people about the method calling and didn't get a single answer. Well the mistake in my code was of method calling as already mentioned by me. Below is the code of doing it the right way

```
mydataList= [dbHandler displayAllResumes]; // mydataList is an NSMutableArray.
numberOfRows = [mydataList count];
[tvMine reloadData];
```

Now everything is working perfectly. Thanks for Your Help :/